# CAST of all columns of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, casting

I am having trouble exporting a file in proper csv in UTF8 from excel. I got the error : "the code page on input column is 1252 and is required to be 65001"

I looked on the error and some solution was to pass the column type to varchar.
I am trying to get my request to cast every columns (I have 191) at the same time and export this from SQL server to csv file, but i can't figure out how to make it work 
My request is :

```
SELECT top 100000 CAST(  * AS varchar(200)) from dbo.AccountingData ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Comment: CAST cannot be used like that. Cast is limited for only one column at a time.    
Refer for more help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Okk thx i'll look for something else